# Is AWS Inspector generated Audit task should be performed on ongoing production servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have AWS Inspector configured for production servers, which generates Audit reports each month.

Audit Report contains: CIS Operating System Security Configuration Benchmarks-1.0
with recommended Tasks to perform on production servers.

My question is do we need to perform all the recommended tasks on production for the security without any checks on development servers or first need to perform tasks in a development environment?